# JavaScript table for loop wrong checkbox value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

I'm for looping data in my page, and they are showing fine, but when I'm trying to click one of three checkboxes and hide desired rows, it seems that get the wrong value.

This is the link of the live page in action.
This is the code that needs to be fixed.

https://musing-jang-0e572c.netlify.com/senate-data.html -> PAGE

https://github.com/Makkoyev/ubiqum-task2/blob/master/assets/js/manipulation.js -> Checkboxes section GitHub

This is the code:

```
(function () {
if (currentURL.indexOf("senate-data.html") == true) {
    getSenate();
    cbs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    targets = document.querySelectorAll("#table tr td:nth-child(2)");
    tr = document.querySelectorAll("#table tr");
    for (i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                // Checkbox is checked..
                console.log("Checkbox checked!", this.value);
                for(i = 0; i < targets.length; i++){
                    if(this.value == targets[i].innerHTML){
                        console.log("Uguale", targets[i]);
                        targets[i].parentNode.classList.add("hide-row");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Checkbox is not checked..
                console.log("Checkbox unchecked!", this.value)
            }
        });
    }
}
if (currentURL.indexOf("house-data.html") == true) {
    getHouse();
}
```

})();

Comment: Post all relevant code directly here as text as an [mcve].

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt **HERE**, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @mplungjan added JS code as requested, thank you for spelling error feedback XD

Answer (score 0):

You likely want something like this

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/29pbve5a/)

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  [...document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")].forEach(function(cbs) { // take all checkboxes 
    cbs.addEventListener('change', function() { // when they change
      var vals = [...document.querySelectorAll(".filters input[type=checkbox]:checked")].map(chk => chk.value); // get all checked values
      [...document.querySelectorAll("#table tr td:nth-child(2)")].forEach(function(target) { // for all cell 2
        target.parentNode.classList.toggle("hide-row",
          vals.indexOf(target.textContent) == -1); // hide the ones NOT in the above list
      });
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Using your code, the error persists. Is the same as mine, Pressing "Democrat" shows "R", pressing "Republican" shows "D" and Independent doesn't work..

Comment: https://musing-jang-0e572c.netlify.com/senate-data.html i have added the website link on main post that is actually live

Comment: Please see  the update. I had to make a fiddle from your rendered HTML

Comment: I would like to ask you also what does it mean:

[...document and -1 (true?)

Comment: It is a spread operator to make the querySelectorAll nodelist an array. The construct is `[...somethingIterableNotArray].someArrayFunction()`

Comment: Same as doing `var checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"); for var(i=0;i<checks.length:i++) { checks[i].bla() }`

Comment: `-1` means not found.  - your code `currentURL.indexOf("senate-data.html") == true` is not correct. It should be `currentURL.indexOf("senate-data.html") > -1`

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I will update everything once I will understand how it works in local :) Really appreciated the time you dedicated for me! Thanks!

Comment: Updated with comments